# Create a dynamic control and AddHandle WITH Values/Brackets

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, addhandler

it seems that adding for example a button `Dim myButton as New Button` and then addHandler to `mySub("lol", 255)` is not possible.

Where `mySub` is `Shared Sub MySub(byRef myString as string, myInteger as Integer)`

So: `addHandler myButton.click, addressOf mySub("lol", 255)` - returns an error saying it does not work with parentheses or whatever.

I somehow see why this might not be possible, so I'm looking for a work-around on this problem.

Please help _jakeCake

Answer (score 2):

First of all the syntax for AddHandler would be:

```
AddHandler myButton.click, AddressOf mySub
```

Secondly the signature of the eventhandler procedure must match the signature of the event like so:

```
Private Sub myButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

    [...]

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time explaining this. Let me just write exactly my case, instead of an example

I have made my own script. First it creates a control, let's say a panel, my code assign the background color, font and so on. The code can also make the control do some actions, for example change the color of another panel. So a script-line would look something like this:

onClick:ChangeBackground-color:#ff44ff for Control-ID:myTestForm

So I try to add a handler to when the control is clicked, to run a sub ChangeBackground_Color(byRef newColor, byRef ControlID)

I hope this make sense

Comment: wow, this is hard to explain, please feel to ask into this, fixing this would save my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look into using a lambda expression when you add the event. When using lambda's in VB.NET the function must return a value and does not support multi-line statements.

```
Dim myButton As New Button
AddHandler myButton.Click, Function(senderObj, args) myFunc("lol", 255)
```

Comment: Workes perfectly, thank you, but I'm not quite sure what you mean with "does not support multi-line statements" could you please explain this :)